# problem with devise register

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I using devise gem for registration but i have problem. my table include: first_name, last_name, email.... but when click http://localhost:3000/users/sign_up. it only show email, password. 
[please see image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nyfmk.png)

I need all show field first_name, last_name... please help me. thanks

```
create_table(:users) do |t|
      t.string :first_name
      t.string :last_name
      t.database_authenticatable :null => false
      t.recoverable
      t.rememberable
      t.trackable
      t.invitable
      t.references :address
      t.integer :current_city_id
      t.integer :hometown_id
      t.string :university
      t.integer :grad_year
      t.string :degree
      # t.confirmable
      # t.lockable :lock_strategy => :failed_attempts, :unlock_strategy => :both
      # t.token_authenticatable


      t.timestamps
    end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to generate devise views with this command

```
rails generate devise:views
```

Than find `registrations/new.html.erb` view and add to it fields that you want.

```
 <p><%= f.label :first_name %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :first_name %></p>
 <p><%= f.label :last_name %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :last_name %></p>
```